# JAX-RS Root and subresource

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jax-rs

Im in the processes of developing a REST Api using JAX-RS and have come across and issue with sub resources. I would like to be able to access a resource directly as well as a sub-resource. For example /products would return me a list of all products. Where as /user/1/products would return products associated with user id 1 only.

Below is the only way I have found to do it. Does anyone else have any neater/better ways of doing it?

Thanks for reading.

Ben.

```
@Path("/users")
public class UserResource {

    @GET
    public List<User> getUsers() {
        /* return all users */
    }

    @GET
    @Path("{id}")
    public User getUser(@PathParam("id") int id) {
        /* return single user */
    }

    @Path("{id}/products/")
    public ProductResource getProductResource(@PathParam("id") int id) {
        return new ProductResource(id);
    }
}

@Path("/products")
public class ProductResource {

    private int id;

    public ProductResource() {
    }

    public ProductResource(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @GET
    public List<Product> getProducts() {
        if(id != 0) {
            /* return products for specific user */
        } else {
            /* return all products */
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would add a method to the ProductResource which handles the URL /products/user/{id}

Comment: Looking at it from a semantic point of view, a product doesn't know anything about a user, and it shouldn't it's not a bidirectional relationship. If it is, then IMO, that's a design flaw. Therefore I'd say there's no need to even involve the `ProductResource` in the `UserResource`. If we have the `ProductResource` handle it, it needs to know about the user, as you are passing the user id. There's no reason you can't lookup the products from the `UserResource` if they are related to the user. Just my to cents. Not sure your complete design, just throwing in a different perspective.